# Getting current method name inside include/require

Tags: php

I currently have this PHP code;

```
private function generateSpecialPage(){
        require_once("/view/pages/special.php");
    }
```

Special.php is a php file mostly filled with html. I'm trying to obtain the name of the current function from inside special.php.

If I echo the magic constant FUNCTION before the require, it echoes "generateSpecialPage", which is what I want. However, if I echo FUNCTION from special.php, it echoes nothing.

I'm able to get the current class' name from inside special.php using get_class($this), I was wondering if there was an equally elegant solution for the current method.

Comment: Better question: why? Your code should not need to care about the function that it runs in. If it does, you're pretty deliberately baking future bugs into it, and preventing any future ease-of-maintenance to the codebase when it requires relocation or page rewrites.

Comment: I changed the names of the function/page and removed the lines  irrelevant with my question, so perhaps that leads to confusion. I have roughly 15 other functions like this one, and they all use "special.php" as a view. The reason it cares what function it runs in is because each implementation of "special.php" results in slightly different pages with slightly different user interactions. I don't want to create a new view for each slight variation; it would be a nightmare to manage. I would rather use the function name than declare/assign to a variable in each function or the class itself.

Comment: This sounds like "when all you have is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail". Instead of including "special.php" inside 15 different functions, magically doing different things in each one, make "special.php" **be** a function, the code for which you can include and then call as `whatever($casevalue)` so you can do your switching in a single, obvious, easy to log, easy to debug, easy to maintain place.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably re-organize your code to change `require_once("/view/pages/special.php")` into a separate function and pass in the function name.

If you call `generateSpecialPage()` a second time, it won't do anything. You could get around this by changing it to `require()`, but then you're loading the file every time which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

A general purpose call stack inspector will let you look back to fetch the caller function, class or object, file, and line. The one I use as part of my framework looks like, in essence:

```
function caller($offset = 0) {
    return (new \Exception)->getTrace()[1+$offset];
}
```

Using this in your `special.php` will yield the desired result:

```
<?php echo caller(1)['function']; ?>
```

The call stack at that point is `special.php -> require -> doSomethingSpecial`, so we use the `1` offset to skip passed the `require` and get the `doSomethingSpecial` frame.

---

---

---

However, you might consider refactoring your view to *receive* parameters, rather than *taking* environmental cues. A general purpose view loader would go something like this:

```
function render($template, array $params = []) {
   extract($params);
   require $template;
}
```

which would then have a template that looked liked:

```
<?php echo "Hello {$caller}" ?>
```

and could be called like:

```
private function doSomethingSpecial() {
    render('special.php', [ 'caller' => __FUNCTION__ ]);
}
```

I realize this is more typing than might be desired, but it affords more flexibility in the long-term, as it decouples the view from the caller.

Answer (score 0):

The required file lives in the same scope as the function that required it.

So you can simply store to a variable before requiring the file:

```
private function generateSpecialPage() {
    $caller = __FUNCTION__;
    require_once '/view/pages/special.php';
}
```

then in `special.php` you have a regular variable `$caller`:

```
<?= "required by {$caller}" ?>
```